# ¿Alguien puede ver cual es el problema con este require? :(

Tags: php

**Para resumir un poco** el funcionamiento de lo que estoy intentando hacer(dejare imágenes donde se ve la estructura de los archivos implicados) : Tengo una archivo index.php que se encuentra en una carpeta llamada admin  este requiere un archivo funciones.php el cual requiere app.php

Es decir: **index.php <- funciones.php <- app.php** (index requiere a funciones,funciones requiere a app)

**El problema** es que la ruta de requerimiento de app.php en funciones.php funciona pefectamente cuando funciones.php es requerido en cualquier archivo que este por fuera de la carpeta admin.

No entiendo porque pasa esto pues entiendo que la ruta de requerimiento no deberia variar ya que es relativa al archivo que la solicita directamente.

**Este es el archivo index.php**, que requiere a funciones.php (ignorar que lo hago con un include, ya lo cambie por un require, el error no venia por allí)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es funciones.php**, que requiere a app.php (de app.php traemos la constante TEMPLATES_URL)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el **mensaje de error** que se ve desde index.php contenido en admin
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dentro de la carpeta admin, tienes una carpeta propiedades, cuando haces '../' para salir solo llegas a admin, te falta salir de la carpeta admin '../../funciones/'

Comment: @JonathanG index.php está por fuera de la carpeta propiedades, me ilusionaste.

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error van _como texto, con formato_. Es mala idea subirlas como imagen: he aquí [el porqué](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerar usar la constante ****DIR**** https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.predefined.php

Para que puedas usar **rutas relativas con respecto al archivo**, y no de que archivo es incluido el php.

Segun tu directorio de carpetas el require cambiaría de esa manera

En admin/index.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/../includes/funciones/funciones.php';
```

En includes/funciones/funciones.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/../app.php';
```